# Why inverse equality does not satisfy in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, matrix-inverse

MATLAB does not satisfy matrix arithmetic for inverse, that is;

```
(ABC)-1 = C-1 * B-1 * A-1
```

in MATLAB,

```
if inv(A*B*C) == inv(C)*inv(B)*inv(A)
   disp('satisfied')
end
```

It does not qualify. When I made it `format long`, I realized that there is difference in points, but it even does not satisfy when I make it `format rat`.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

Very likely a [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples). Note that [the `format` function affects only how numbers display, not how MATLAB computes or saves them.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) So setting it to `rat` won't help the inaccuracy.

I haven't tested, but you may try the [Fractions Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24878-fractions-toolbox) for exact rational number arithmetics, which should give an equality to above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this (MATLAB R2011a):

```
a = 1e10;
>> b = inv(a)*inv(a)
b =
  1.0000e-020
>> c = inv(a*a)
c =
  1.0000e-020
>> b==c
ans =
     0
>> format hex
>> b
b =
   3bc79ca10c924224
>> c
c =
   3bc79ca10c924223
```

When MATLAB calculates the intermediate quantities `inv(a)`, or `a*a` (whether `a` is a scalar or a matrix), it by default stores them as the closest double precision floating point number - which is not exact. So when these slightly inaccurate intermediate results are used in subsequent calculations, there will be round off error.

Instead of comparing floating point numbers for direct equality, such as `inv(A*B*C) == inv(C)*inv(B)*inv(A)`, it's often better to compare the absolute difference to a threshold, such as `abs(inv(A*B*C) - inv(C)*inv(B)*inv(A)) < thresh`. Here `thresh` can be an arbitrary small number, or some expression involving `eps`, which gives you the smallest difference between two numbers at the precision at which you're working.

The `format` command only controls the display of results at the command line, not the way in which results are internally stored. In particular, `format rat` does not make MATLAB do calculations symbolically. For this, you might take a look at the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic). `format hex` is often even more useful than `format long` for diagnosing floating point precision issues such as the one you've come across.